# Strange behavior for 'free' in C

Tags: c, memory-management, free, calloc

I was writing a code to check if two functions I wrote to allocate and deallocate memory worked. The two functions were essentially

```
int createBaseName(char ***imageName, char **groupName, char *name)
{
    *imageName = calloc(BASELINEC, sizeof(char *)); //This is a 2D array (array of str)
    *groupName = calloc(MINILINE, sizeof(char)); // This is a 1D array (just an str)

    sprintf(*groupName, "%s_BGr.fbi", name);
    for(bb = 0; bb < BASELINEC; bb++) {
       (*imageName)[bb]  = (char *)calloc(MINILINE, sizeof(char));
        if (bb < 9)
           sprintf((*imageName)[bb], "%s_BIm_00%d.fbi", name, bb+1);
        else if (bb < 99) 
           sprintf((*imageName)[bb], "%s_BIm_0%d.fbi", name, bb+1);
        else
           sprintf((*imageName)[bb], "%s_BIm_%d.fbi", name, bb+1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

and

```
int freeBaseName(char **imageName, char *groupName)
{
   int  bb;

   for(bb = 0; bb < BASELINEC; bb++)
      free(imageName[bb]);

   free(imageName);
   free(groupName);

   return 0;
}
```

In the program I wrote to check these two functions, I accidentally called `createBaseName` and `freeBaseName` one after the other, and *then* I was attempting to print out `imageName` and `groupName`. This resulted in `groupName` printing just fine, and about a 120 of 400 names of `imageName` printing fine before it segfaulted.

**QUESTION:** Why wasn't the `free`-ing of the memory working? Or does it take time to free the memory?

Comment: For your formatting three-digit numbers with leading zeroes, why not use the format `"%03d"`? No `if` statements needed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/13005. It's about local variables in C++ rather than `calloc` in C, but the same analogy applies.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Didn't know that I could do that! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`free()` function only marks a memory block as "free". That means, that at any moment, it cam be used by other function. It does not clean up the memory as it supposed to be handled by the program that will get this memory block next time.

What you actually done, is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 2):

When you `free` a memory, you just loose control over it. You release the memory for any other use. It does not get overwritten or occupied by other function or variable immediately. But it can be used by other function or variable at any unknown time. Until then, you will be able to access the memory. But as one cannot be sure about the time when it will be used by others, the **behaviour** is **undefined**.

- In case you want to make sure that the memory become inaccessible using the same variable, set them to **`NULL`** after `free`ing.

Answer (score 1):

`free` marks the memory as being free for reuse. After `free` you are responsible for not attempting to use the memory again. It is possible that the memory is still intact after freeing, hence your `groupName` printing fine. However it could also have been reallocated, hence the segfault in `imageName`

Answer (score 1):

When freeing memory, the pointers still point to the memory that was allocated, and its contents may (or may not) be overwritten by other data. This is why it seems to work some times. *Undefined behavior* tends to be, well, undefined.